# In my Firebase database I want to update isDownloaded value of node where sender and receiver matches sone specific value

Tags: java

As shown in image I want to update isDownloaded value when receiver value matches “MYwL1G4SmGRTwL...” and sender value matches “4YFAcsjwTIQ5r....” So for this what Firebase query should I write.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6ATB.jpg)